# Qual é a forma mais fácil de fazer um slide com BootStrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estava seguindo o seguinte tutorial para fazer um slide:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

O Design eu consegui implantar na minha página, pois é praticamente só copiar e colar, segui o exemplo com legenda..

Daí travei na hora de implementar o Javascript para começar o *slide*, do intervalo e os eventos do toque nos ícones... Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo do JavaScript? Não sou nada bom nessa linguagem, sei que to pedindo demais, mas é porque tentei de muita formas, tentei ate com outro tipo de slide que achei e nada... Só preciso do JavaScript funcional seguindo o exemplo do link.

Comment: [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/mmarcon/UWbrQ/) tem um exemplo funcional...

Comment: Ops, foi mal, esse não é com bootstrap. Mas dá uma olhada [neste](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/XFcSv/), que tem até algumas personalizações.

Comment: Valeu esse exemplo resolveu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

talvez esse script lhe sirva de partida:

```
$(function () {
    $('#homeCarousel').carousel({
        interval:2000,
        pause: "false"
    });
    $('#playButton').click(function () {
        $('#homeCarousel').carousel('cycle');
        alert('clicou no play');
    });
    $('#pauseButton').click(function () {
        $('#homeCarousel').carousel('pause');
        alert('clicou no pause');
    });
});
```